# how do you ignore non-test files with ava?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ava

Can I ignore a setup or support folder so that ava doesn't try to run the files inside?

I have some common utility files used for mocking that should logically live inside the `test/` folder alongside tests but I don't want to run them as tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore files prefix them with an underscore `_` or an exclamation mark `!`

---

In ava's documentation for [configuration](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/06-configuration.md) under the files bulletpoint it states:

> Files with an underscore prefix are ignored

And the documentation at the top also explicitly states:

> To ignore files, prefix the pattern with an `!` (exclamation mark).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, see the `files` examples in https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/06-configuration.md. If you prefix a pattern with `!` then any matching files will not be considered to be test files.